# Finding the optimal stepping angles for a 5 level approximation of a sine wave

Tags: discrete-mathematics, trigonometry, continuity

I have an interesting problem.

Consider a five-level waveform that is defined piece-wise as
$$f(\theta)=\cases
{0 \ \ \ \ \  0 \leq \theta <\alpha_1 \\
0.5 \ \ \ \ \ \alpha_1 \leq \theta <\alpha_2 \\
1 \ \ \ \ \ \ \alpha_2 \leq \theta <\pi-\alpha_2 \\
0.5 \ \ \ \ \ \ \pi-\alpha_2 \leq \theta <\pi-\alpha_1 \\
0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \pi-\alpha_1 \leq \theta <\pi+\alpha_1 \\
-0.5 \ \ \ \ \ \pi+\alpha_1 \leq \theta <\pi+\alpha_2 \\
-1 \ \ \ \ \ \ \pi+\alpha_2 \leq \theta <2\pi-\alpha_2 \\
-0.5 \ \ \ \ \ \ 2\pi-\alpha_2 \leq \theta <2\pi-\alpha_1 \\
0 \ \ \ \ \ \ 2\pi-\alpha_1 \leq \theta <2\pi}
$$
Note that $\alpha_1 < \alpha_2$.

The fundamental voltage component may be derived as
$$f_{fund.}(\theta) = \left( \frac{2}{\pi} \cos(\alpha_1)+\frac{2}{\pi} \cos(\alpha_2) \right) \sin(\theta)$$

Here, we can assume that $A=\left( \frac{2}{\pi} \cos(\alpha_1)+\frac{2}{\pi} \cos(\alpha_2) \right)$ is a known variable.

For a fixed $A$, there are still an infinite number of possibilities for $\{ \alpha_1, \alpha_2\}$, even under the condition that $\alpha_1<\alpha_2$.

Therefore, my question is: Is there an analytic method to determine $\{ \alpha_1, \alpha_2\}$ (for fixed $A$) such that the peak value of $f(\theta)-f_{fund.}(\theta)$ is minimized?

I know that piece-wise functions can be difficult to work with, but I am hoping that someone more clever than myself may help to point me in the right direction.

Thanks a lot.